# getting 400 badrequest while passing multipart file in request in Junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

when I am trying to write the junit for my controller class, I am getting 400 bad request.

In console , i can see below error:

> logException Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present

this is my Junit

```java
@Test
void testExcelFile() throws Exception {

    FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream("path of the file");
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "myexcelFile.xlsx", "multipart/form-data", inputFile); 

    Mockito.when(service.upload((MultipartFile) file)).thenReturn("received");
            
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/uploadData",file)
            .param("file",file.getName()).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    MvcResult result = 
    mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isAccepted()).andReturn();
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED.value(), result.getResponse().getStatus()); 
}
```

This is my controller class

```java
@PostMapping("/uploadData")
public ResponseEntity<String> save(@RequestParam(required = true)  MultipartFile file) {
    if(ExcelHelper.checkExcelFormat(file)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.upload(file),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please upload excel file only");
}
```

Please help what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-multipart-post-request-test

Comment: MockMultipartFile file2 = new MockMultipartFile("file", "importTemplate.xlsx", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, inputFile.toString().getBytes()); 
    MockMultipartFile file1 
       = new MockMultipartFile(
         "file", 
         "importTemplate.xlsx", 
         MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
         "Hello, World!".getBytes()
       );          @Phil, I tried that way also but still getting Bad request.

Comment: You tried _what_, exactly? The code in that article is quite different to the code in your question (which is where all code should be, not in the comments)

Comment: FYI, you're setting the wrong mime-type for your file. For an XLSX file, it should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Thanks @Phil, After correcting Mime-type , it worked fine.Thank You.